# Ktorrent problem (lagging) on kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, ktorrent

im using kubuntu 15.10 updated from 14.04 lts to 15.04 first and afther that i updated to 15.10 , so i have one problem , when i start downloading torrent with ktorrent suddenly afther few seconds ktorrent remains inactive (lagging and downloads really slow like 5-10 mb afther 10 min ....) i cant do nothing with it ... i tryed to remove ktorrent using terminal and reinstalling it .... same thing happends afther reinstall , can someone help me , thanks !

My system is laptop compaq cq-56  , 2core @ 2,3 ghz , ati radeon hd 4250 256@32 ,320 hdd .

Answer (score 0):

Let;s try something else...!! I have already done this until they fix Ktorrent

Download & Install another client in C++ written an Qt..!!

Do these steps..

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

enjoy it..!!! It also has a web interface so to connect remotely leaving your PC open to download any torrent you like ...all that remotely.
Have fun.!